# iOS - Reload UIView when tab icon clicked?

Tags: ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application that uses a UITabBarController, and inside each tab I have Navigation Controllers.
I would like to make one of the views reload itself after an action happens in another view, so that when the user goes back to that view - it's updated.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to put your loading code into [viewWillAppear:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW16) instead of `viewDidLoad`. While `viewDidLoad` may only get called once, when your view is initialized, `viewWillAppear:` is called any time your view controller is about to be presented, whether it be in the tab bar, in a navigation controller, etc., which gives you a nice hook to implement loading and layout functionality.

Comment: How about if you are already in "the tab page" and want to refresh it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. that worked perfectly. For anyone reading this here is my code. It works but be warned, I'm new to iOS and objective-C so caveat emptor.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated
{
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/image.jpg"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update the UI
            self.img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        });
    });
}
```